# Android check low connectivity mode Wifi or Data network

Tags: android, android-wifi, connectivity

I have read quite alot of posts on Checking internet connection. But my problem is how do I detect limited and/or low connectivity? Pinging google.com continously is not the answer. 
A possible solution is keep on checking RSSI Strength and if the value goes higher then lets say -70 then we check for connection.

Has anyone a better solution as how to detect limited connectivity?

Comment: These are two different things. What do you want to check? Internet connection or WLAN?

Comment: In layman terms I need to check if the devices has low connectivity or not

Comment: So you want to check the internet connection? Doesn't matter if the connection is using WLAN, GSM or LTE?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).
There is an example how to determine the internet connection and how to determine the type of a connection.

You could also take a look at `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for an answer to this on one of my projects rather extensively. All that I could suggest is to ping google and then get the response time. You could create your own method of comparison like, response >= 500ms = slow connection.

You could also detect whether or not the device is on 2G/3G and depending on what you consider slow.

Lastly, if you can check if the wifi connection speed using the following: (I haven't used this myself)

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManger.getConnectionInfo();
int mbps = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
```

I really hope that helps mate, happy coding.